# How to select the first "lowest" (first valley) number in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I would to select the first valley of the list of coordinates below. It should be `{3, 1}`.

```
list = {{1, 7}, {2, 4}, {3, 1}, {4, 4}, {5, 9}, {6, 8}, {7, 3}, {8, 1}, {9, 4}, {10, 9}};
```

I thought it could be done like this

```
Select[list, #1[[2]] > #2[[2]] &, 1]
```

but that does not work. How can it be done then?

Comment: No, its the second coordinate that has to be lower than the previous 2.-coordinate...

Answer (score 5):

```
list = {{1, 7}, {2, 4}, {3, 1}, {4, 4}, {5, 9}, {6, 8}, {7, 3}, {8,  1},{9, 4}, {10, 9}}; 
Last@First@Split[list, Last[#1] > Last[#2] &]
(* {3,1} *)
```

or

```
Catch[Fold[If[#2[[2]] > #1[[2]], Throw[#1], #2] &, First@list, Rest@list]]
(* {3,1} *)
```

or

```
First@NestWhile[Rest, list, #2[[1, 2]] < #1[[1, 2]] &, 2, Infinity, -1]
(* {3,1} *)
```

Comment: This seems to work. Thank you!

Comment: But I do not understand why the option of comparison between the elements of the list is not possible in Select[] and Position[], but only in Sort[] and Split[] as you propose...

Comment: @SimonLausen, my pleasure.

Comment: For `Select` the selection test function takes a single argument; it is applied to each element sepearately to decide whether the element qualifies for selection. For `Split`, `Sort`, `Union` ... the test function takes two arguments.

Answer (score 3):

FYI: `Select` examines only one element at a time.  To use `Select` in the way you want, [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Partition.html) the `list` into adjacent pairs:

```
list = {{1, 7}, {2, 4}, {3, 1}, {4, 4}, {5, 9}, {6, 8}, {7, 3}, {8, 1}, {9, 4}, {10, 9}};

Select[Partition[list, 2, 1], #[[2, 2]] > #[[1, 2]] &, 1][[1, 1]]
(* {3, 1} *)
```